# Select class not contained in div

Tags: javascript, jquery, containers, selection

Is it possible to select a class of a page without selecting the same class which were encapsulated in a special div?

something like:

```
$(!".container").$(".selectedClass").dosomething..
```

or

```
$(".selectedClass").parent(!"container").dosomething..
```

Here's some example...

```
<div class="blah">
    <div class="remove"><div>
</div>
<div class="blaha">
    <div class="remove"><div>
</div>
<div class="dont_remove_remove_here">
    <div class="remove"><div>
</div>
<div class="blahblah">
    <div class="remove"><div>
</div>
```

I want to remove all classes "remove" but not in the "dont_remove_remove_here" container.

Comment: Can you provide some sample HTML, and be explicit as to what you would and would not like to select? jQuery does have [`not` selectors](http://api.jquery.com/?ns0=1&s=.not).

Comment: Can you better explain what you are trying to ask? I'm a little confused by your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would never use the other 'div:not(.container)' answers on this page in production code because it would lead to extremely slow performance.

The code below is much more efficient:

```
      $(".remove").each(function(i,elt) {
        if (!$(elt).parent().hasClass("dont-remove")) {
           $(elt).remove();
        }
      });
```

Comment: <div class="blah">
 <div class="remove"><div>
</div>
<div class="blaha">
 <div class="remove"><div>
</div>
<div class="dont_remove_remove_here">
 <div class="remove"><div>
</div>
<div class="blahblah">
 <div class="remove"><div>
</div>

I want to remove all classes "remove" but not in the "dont_remove_remove_here" container...
hope this helps...

Comment: In that case, all you need to do is use parent() instead of parents() -- let me edit this above answer for that scenario

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly this should work, but it will be quite slow. Plus you may want to change div to something else, or further refine the first part.

```
$("div:not(.container)").find(".selectedClass")
```

Answer (score 0):

And the answer is..

```
$("div:not(.container)").remove(".remove");
```